# Tomcat 7 Access denied

Tags: tomcat

I cannot login to the manager application for Tomcat 7.0.25. Even with the right credentials I always get a 403 Access Denied. What am I missing?

**tomcat-users.xml:**

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="pass" role='admin-gui,manager-gui'/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: try wrinting roles="admin-gui,manager-gui" i.e with an extra 's' in role and using"" instead of ''

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try adding a 's' to your role attribute name so that the <user> tag reads:

```
<user username="admin" password="pass" roles='admin-gui,manager-gui'/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot…! One small little s…